# Command Line Calculator in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, command-line, calculator

I want to implement a command line application in C/Objective C which will act as a calculator of more than two numbers.

E.g ./calc 5 + 4 * 6 
= 29

I just need an idea or simple algorithm to start. I will appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm you want is the infix notation to postfix notation converter.
You can find some more info on it over here.

http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/infix-postfix/index.htm.

**EDIT:** I am not sure if this will help, but here is an implementation in Java. I'm not familiar with Objective-C

```
    // converts a infix string to postfix string
private void convertInfixToPostfix(){
    // create an empty operand stack
    operatorStack = new Stack<>();
    Operator operator = null;
    Operand operand = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < expressionTokens.size(); i++){
        String token = expressionTokens.get(i);
        Element element = new Element(token);

        if(element.isOperand(token)){ // check if element is operand
            // add the element to the postfix string
            operand = new Operand(element.getStringValue());
            postFixString.add(operand);
        }
        else if(operatorStack.isEmpty()){ 
            // push the token to the operator stack, its an operator
            operator = new Operator(element.getStringValue());
            operatorStack.push(operator);
        }
        else {
            operator = new Operator(element.getStringValue());
            while(!operatorStack.isEmpty() && 
                    (operatorStack.peek().getPrecedence() 
                    <= operator.getPrecedence()))    
                postFixString.add(operatorStack.pop());

            operatorStack.push(operator);
        }
    }

    // add the rest of the operator stack to the postfix string
    while(!operatorStack.isEmpty()){
        Operator remainingOperator = operatorStack.pop();
        postFixString.add(remainingOperator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the idea :)